# Change value of hidden field when image clicked (rails and jquery)

Tags: jquery, image, input

I'm trying to change the value of a hidden input field to the source of a clicked image.  For some reason, the field isn't getting the value.  What am I doing wrong?

Images...

```
<li><h><img src="/images/frame1.png"></h></li>
<li><h><img src="/images/frame2.png"></h></li>
<li><h><img src="/images/frame3.png"></h></li>
```

Hidden field:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :frame, :id => "frame", :name => "frame" %>
```

Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function() { 
    $("h img").click(function() {
        var imageId = $("img").attr("src");
        $("#frame").val(imageId);
    });
});​
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $("h img").click(function() {
        var imageId = $(this).attr("src"); // or can use this.src instead
        $("#frame:hidden").val(imageId);
    });
```